# java writing to a file to find the finalAverage

Tags: java, filewriter

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class BottleCapPrize{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        // create .txt file
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("05.06 Desk Check.txt"));

        // create Scanner object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // prompt user for number of trials
        System.out.print("Please enter how much times you want to perform the trial: ");

        // create variable for recieving input
        int input = in.nextInt();

        // create count variable
        int count = 1;

        // create range variable
        int range;

        // create average
        double average = 0.0;

        // create Random object
        Random random = new Random();

        // while loop for trials
        while(count <= input){

            // create Random range
            range = random.nextInt(5) + 1;

            // calculate average
            average += range;

            // increment count
            count++;
        }

        // calculate final average
        double finalAverage = average/count;

        // display final average
        System.out.println("The average of you winning the prize is: "
                + finalAverage);

        // display average in file
        outFile.println("The average of you winning the prize is: "
                + finalAverage);
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I want it to not only display the final average on the console but also in a file called "05.06 DeskCheck.txt" which was created in the code above, but when I run it, it just displays the finalAverage in the console and opens a blank file called"05.06 Desk Check.txt". How can I fix this so that it will also display the finalAverage in the file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the `PrintWriter` in order to flush contents to the file. Try adding this:

```
outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll have to close the file..

```
outfile.close();
```